# Rolling.apply function

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, mean

I have a datetime indexed series as :

```
In [343]:h1w.head(5)
Out[343]: 2014-08-01 00:00:00    0.469112
          2014-08-01 00:00:01    0.186249
          2014-08-01 00:00:02   -1.322810
          2014-08-01 00:00:03   -2.458442
          2014-08-01 00:00:04   -1.246330

          Freq: S, dtype: float64
```

I am practicing the lambda function and rolling window functions. I see an example to calculate mean absolute deviation as using the code below.

```
mean_abs_dev = lambda x: np.fabs(x - x.mean()).mean()
pd.rolling_apply(h1w, 5, mean_abs_dev)
```

What does the .mean() after (x - x.mean()) signify here ??

Comment: `x - x.mean()` is the vector of deviations from the mean, `np.fabs(x - x.mean())` is the vector of absolute deviations (i.e. absolute value of the deviations), and therefore `np.fabs(x - x.mean()).mean()` is exactly what you want: the mean absolute deviation.

Comment: Thanks IanS, that explains well.